# MySql subquery extraction as per number of days and other criterias

Tags: mysql, sql

We are facing some problems in building a mysql Query.

Let suppose we save two columns col1 and col2 . Let suppose col1 value is abcd. So we need to find all those rows whose col1 = abcd and after 10 days col2 value is product1 .

Let me try to elaborate with example.

[image]

Let me try to break out it into parts

1) All rows whose col1 = abcd and extract there wlid,date

2) Match wlid and date with other rows and col2 = product1 . and date should be more then 10 days. So In this case only 4th row should be output

**EDIT** Our desired output is 4th Row since by extracting all wlid whose col1 = abcd, so we get row1 and our 2nd condition whose date is more than date which is extracted in 1st condition and col2  value is product1 . So extracted output is only 4th Row

Table  in Text form

Sr.No  wlid  col1  col2      date

1      1     abcd  product1  2017-06-10 04:16:28

2      2     abc   product2  2017-06-12 04:16:28

3      1     ab    product1  2017-06-17 04:16:28

4      1     a     product1  2017-06-21 04:16:28

5      1     a     product2  2017-06-21 04:16:28

Comment: update your question and add the expected  result please (and use text and not image only SO is not a fre coding service)

Comment: hi @scaisEdge I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
mysql> select * from demo;

+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
| sr_no | wlid | col1 | col2      | date                |
+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
|     1 |    1 | abcd | product 1 | 2017-06-10 04:16:28 |
|     2 |    2 | abc  | product 2 | 2017-06-12 04:16:28 |
|     3 |    1 | ab   | product 1 | 2017-06-17 04:16:28 |
|     4 |    1 | a    | product 1 | 2017-06-21 04:16:28 |
|     5 |    1 | a    | product 2 | 2017-06-21 04:16:28 |
+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select d1.* from demo d1 inner join demo d2 on d1.col2 = d2.col2 where datediff(d1.date,d2.date) >= 10;
+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
| sr_no | wlid | col1 | col2      | date                |
+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
|     4 |    1 | a    | product 1 | 2017-06-21 04:16:28 |
+-------+------+------+-----------+---------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @yusuf but you forget to add a condition where d2 col2 needs to be product 1

Comment: Yes. This is a more generic query which'll give you where ever `col1 = col2`. What you say is a simple statement in `where` condition. Do you want me to structure that query as well? Also, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: your query is absolutely correct and thanks for help. I am just saying  in your query that part is missing. By the ways thanks a lot, exact this query we are looking for

Comment: Hi this query runs well on small data but our data is more than 3 lakh rows and we index col1,col2,date columns but still performance is very very poor is there anyway to improve it

Comment: your answer contains duplicate rows

Comment: 1. Duplicates can be easily addressed by using `distinct` or `group by` depending upon how your dataset is.
2. The above query is slow because it's not using the `index` because of the datediff function. 
Learnings - (a) specify the table structure (PKs / indexes before hand). (b) Execute `explain [your query]` to check the execution plan and usage of keys (I cannot do that because I don't have access to your data). (c) Issues like duplicates etc can be handled at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

select * from table as t 
inner join (select * from table as t2 where t2.col1 = 'abcd') on t2.Sr.No = t.Sr.No
where t2.wlid = t.wlid and t.col2 = 'product1' and t.date > 
DATE_ADD(t2.date, INTERVAL 10 DAY);

I have not tested though, let me know if it works for you.